# setOnClickListener not working and throwing error

Tags: android, android-layout

**Below is my program and I am getting this error:**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (welcome)  welcome.java    /testcalculator/src/com/testcalculator  line 31 Java Problem
```

**welcome.java**

```
package com.testcalculator;
public class welcome extends Activity{
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome1);
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        playBtn.setOnItemClickListener();
        Button exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
        exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.playBtn :
            i = new Intent(this, testcalculator.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.exitBtn :
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
   }
```

The problem is, I have all the required import options in my problem but still I am getting error message.

Comment: Empty lines are of no help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing your Activity class as the OnClickListener in this line:

```
exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

However, your class needs to explicitly declare that it is implementing the `View.OnCLickListener` interface. Change your class declaration line to this:

```
public class welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

---

A couple of other things to note:

You wrote `playBtn.setOnItemClickListener()`. Perhaps you meant `playBtn.setOnClickListener(this)`? Buttons don't have OnItemClickListeners

You can also set an OnClickListener without having the activity class itself implement the interface by declaring an anonymous class. Like this:

```
playBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // playBtn code
    }
});

exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // exitBtn code
    }
});
```

This way is used more often because it is more readable. By segregating the button onClick code, you can easily tell which button does what, as opposed to putting it all into one method and having the class itself implement OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
playBtn.setOnItemClickListener();
```

It should be setOnClickListener(this), as done for the Exit Button. Does exit button work?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting common onClick method for both OnClickListener classes that is wrong. Try to have two different onClick methods for both button's OnClickListener class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `this` as `exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);`, you have to declare that your Activity will implements the interface `OnClickListener`

```
public class welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome1);


    //////// MENU  //////////
    Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i = new Intent(this, testcalculator.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Button exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
    exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Or change your class to implement the OnClickListener like: `public class welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener`

Comment: public class welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener fixed the problem and I removed following:

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Answer (score 0):

Import the following:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

You write this line on top of main activity and implement onClickListener,

```
public class welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write

```
playBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // code here
    }
});
```

and for the same button too. I think it will be more better than your version. :)