# Adding onClickListener to List

Tags: android, listview, listener

I'm pretty new to android and I've got a question. I'm playing around with a simple Twitter client tutorial which is on github. however I can't manage to get a `onClickListener` working properly. How can I retrieve the position of any item on the list that is being clicked on?

I've tried playing around by combining tutorials with no luck yet.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/cacois/TweetView/blob/progress_bar/src/com/example/TweetItemAdapter.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.Example.Tweet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TweetItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;
    private Activity activity;
    public ImageManager imageManager;

    public TweetItemAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
        super(a, textViewResourceId, tweets);
        this.tweets = tweets;
        activity = a;

        imageManager = 
            new ImageManager(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView username;
        public TextView message;
        public ImageView image;
        public ProgressBar progress; //ADDED
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {        
            LayoutInflater vi = 
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
            holder.message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
            holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            holder.progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar); //ADDED
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        final Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
        if (tweet != null) {
            holder.username.setText(tweet.username);
            holder.message.setText(tweet.message);
            holder.image.setTag(tweet.image_url);
            imageManager.displayImage(tweet.image_url, activity, holder.image, holder.progress); //CHANGED
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok figured out what to do. here is a solution in case someone has the same problem:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.v("position", String.valueOf(position));
    }
});
```

this goes in the main activity right after listView.setAdapter

Answer (score 2):

In the getView method, use this:

```
v.addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do some stuff with the view that has been clicked
    }
});
```

When you click an item, the appropriate function will be called because you now specified what has to happen with each view when you click it.

Comment: There's not a good way from this method to find the index in the list of the view that was clicked.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. i actually tried this before but didnt manage to get the position to work, all i managed to do is display a toast whenever something was clicked. any ideas how to get display the position?

Comment: Why would you need the position if you're disposing of the view that was clicked? You could use a variable in the adapterclass that you increment each time getView is called. You can use that variable in the onClick method so this variable can be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than attaching an OnClickListener to the view, it's easier to just override `onListItemClick` in your ListActivity. If you aren't using a ListActivity, use `setOnItemClickListener` on the ListView itself to register an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` object.

**EDIT**

Assuming that you are subclassing ListActivity to hold your list, do something like this:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    // . . .

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // process click on item #position
        Tweet item = (Tweet) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. can you give me an example with code? i'm new to android and i have no idea how to do those things. i just need a way to show me the position of a clicked item, i can take the rest from there i guess :) thanks in advance

Comment: hi, i tried this and it crashes when running. here is the logcat: http://pastebin.com/YjuQ3kpm any idea what could be wrong? i dont get any errors in eclipse....this is what the whole thing looks like: http://pastebin.com/KWhp3QcZ

Comment: @robs - The key message in the logcat is: "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'". It looks like your main.xml doesn't specify a ListView with the right id; this is an absolute requirement for subclassing ListActivity. If you want to use a ListView in an activity that isn't a ListActivity, use the second method I described (using an OnItemClickListener, which can be an inner class or implemented by the activity itself).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)`

and

`http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html`

When an item is clicked the `onItemClick` will be passed the position of the item click and you can use this and the `ArrayAdapter` `getItem(int position)` to access the item and perform the operation.

Attach it to your view, this can be done in the activity on the adapter but I would suggest using it in the activity like so:

```
final ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt,
                long paramLong) {
            // TODO whatever you want to do to this item               
        }
    });
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. ive tried putting that piece of code everywhere without luck.. i am new to android development and id really appreciate it if you could show me where exactly im supposed to put that in the code. thanks in advance, rob

Comment: @robs I have updated the answer because I included a object which I have created that may have been confusing, now it might be more clear. You would need to post more code, all you have at present is the adapter, post the activity where you set the adapter and I will show where the code goes.

Comment: sorry looks like the link to the github wasnt posted in my initial post. here is the link to the main activity: https://github.com/cacois/TweetView/blob/progress_bar/src/com/example/Example.java

Answer (score 0):

Implement `OnItemClickListener` in your activity and add the unimplemented methods.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            System.out.println(position);
}
```

Set `onItemClickListener` to your list object like

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

your class should implements following

```
public class YourClass extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
```

Thats it.

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. ive added the first part in the tweetitemadapter which showed fine but i dont know where to put "list.setOnItemClickListener(this);". ive tried adding "listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);" to the example.java you can see in the github, but i get the message "The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not 
 applicable for the arguments (Example)". sorry for my noobness

Comment: No you should not add it in TweetItemAdapter . you need to implement the above in your Activity(where you create object to list view and set your TweetItemAdapter).

Comment: hmmm tried that and it still doesnt work. i'm using "listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);" right below listView.setAdapter in my main activity and eclipse is giving me an error

Comment: Please share the error. Did you implement OnItemClickListener  to your activity.. i have edited my answer please check.

Comment: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (Example)

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684499/setonclicklistener-not-working-and-throwing-error   also share your activity class code

Comment: my activity class is here: https://github.com/cacois/TweetView/blob/progress_bar/src/com/example/Example.java

Comment: apart from some import lines missing, everything looks ok.            ->import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Comment: the import lines are actually in the code, just forgot to add them to the pastebin cause ive been trying out multiple suggested solutions. but it doesnt work. eclipse says all the imports are there but doesnt like the "this" argument. if i type "null" instead of "this" then eclipse doesnt give me an error but the app FCs when launching..weird