# ListView OnItemClickListener doesn't get fired

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have set up an android project with a navigation drawer and i'm working with fragments

And the activity_main.xml contains the following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:name="com.waldispd.homecast.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment change:

```
StaffelFragment newFragment = new StaffelFragment();
newFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment).commit();
```

fragment_staffel.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/staffelList"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the problem is, when i want to receive the item click from the listview item, it doesn't get fired. Also scrolling is not possible on the listview

item click listener :

```
ListView staffelListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.staffelList);
staffelListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
     {
         LoadStaffel(position);
     }
 });
 staffelListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item, staffelTitel));
```

on most other questions they said to add 'android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" ' but that didn't solve the problem. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: are you sure it is not fired? Did you try logging it?

Comment: I've added a break-point to LoadStaffel(position) and also in the function, newer got in (yes i'm in debuging mode)

Comment: Can you post the whole getView()? It´s so error prone that it could be something you wouldn't expect at all.

Comment: Was a serious problem with the fragment handling (add instead of replacing), now i can scroll and hopefully soon click on the items

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `staffelListView.setOnItemClickListener` use `staffelListView.setOnClickListener`

Comment: ends in an 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead' exception

Comment: try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716230/adding-onclicklistener-to-list#answer-8790561

Comment: Now i have it right after the setAdapter, with no change

Answer (score 0):

Try using this inside each child layouts

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and remove other thing which you are doing for this. Also from listview.

or
remove this

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and if you need `android:descendantFocusability` try this

```
parent.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        ((ViewGroup) v).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "button layouts"? I havn't used buttons at all.

this doesn't solve the scroll problem, nor the problem with the click event raising.

Comment: In my case in fragment_staffel.xml the ListView? This doesn't solve any problems at all too :/

Comment: I slowly have the feeling that something isn't correct with the fragments. LoadStaffelFragment seems to get called multiple times, maybe thats the problem. But with fragmentmanager.replace(...) the view doesnt get visible, is it correct to call every time fragmentmngr.Add(..)?

Answer (score 0):

**try with this..**

```
staffelListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
     {
         LoadStaffel(position);
     }
 });
 staffelListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item, staffelTitel));
```

Comment: doesn't work because I don't need to use the compat library. And it always puts AdapterView or Adapterviewcompat before the OnItemclickListener()